# Alternative to macOSX sparsebundles on windows

Tags: windows, macos, windows-explorer, encryption

After encrypting a bunch of files in sparsebundles on my Mac I discovered I can't open them on Windows.

Is there an alternative file type, like sparsebundles, that allows encryption and can be read in both Mac and Windows?

Comment: Well, the direct equivalent is a dynamically-expanding VHD image. It’s not macOS-compatible of course. You need to look for third-party software, especially if you want to be able to easily modify files inside the encrypted container.

Comment: @DanielB Is there any other file type that can be encrypted and that works on both OS? I just need a file that takes as much space as the contents it holds.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to read the sparsebundles in Windows, you can use open source [HFSExplorer](http://www.catacombae.org/hfsexplorer/). It can read encrypted sparsebundles (as well as actual HFS/HFS+ drives).